# Get the lowest value on a List<> array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

```
int numbers;
List<int> arrayInt = new List<int>();

for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
{
    Console.Write("Enter 10 integers: ");
    numbers = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    arrayInt.Add(i);

    if (i == 10)
    {
        int[] output = arrayInt.ToArray();
        int min = output.Min(); 
        Console.WriteLine(min); //outputs 0
    }
}
```

The user enters 10 integers and adds it into the `arrayInt` list.

After the user enters 10 integers, the second `if` gets the lowest integer by converting my `arrayInt` list to an array. I used the `.Min()` to get the lowest int but it still outputs `0`.

What's wrong in my code?

For ex., `I enter 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1` then the `Console.WriteLine(min)` should output `1` because it's the lowest integer.

Comment: This is easily identified and fixed using the awesome, built in debugger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest a couple of changes:

1. As others have said, you're adding the counter variable to the list rather than the user input. That is easily fixed.
2. You have additional logic inside your loop to do something different when you reach the last index. Instead of this, you should just modify your loop condition so that it exits at the appropriate time, then do your final steps after the loop has completed. This way, the only job of the loop is to gather user input.
3. You should use `Int.TryParse` instead of `Parse`, because it will return `false` if the user gives invalid input, in which case we can just tell them to try again.
4. You don't need to convert the `List` to an `Array`. There is an extension method for Lists that will give you the minimum value. You just need `using System.Linq` at the top of your file to use it.

Here's the code:

```
static void Main()
{
    var allNumbers = new List<int>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Console.Write($"Enter integer #{i + 1}: ");

        int input;
        while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input))
        {
            Console.Write(" - Invalid input, try again: ");
        }

        allNumbers.Add(input);
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"\nThank you! The smallest number you entered is: {allNumbers.Min()}");

    Console.Write("\nDone!\nPress any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: What does the  `$` and `#` do on your `#{i + 1}`?

Comment: The `#` is just regular string output - it's displayed to the user

Comment: The `$` expands variables and equations in the string that are wrapped in `{}`. See [String Interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interpolated-strings)

Answer (score 4):

```
arrayInt.Add(i);
```

You're adding i to your list instead of what you're inputting. The code above isn't actually using the variable `numbers`

Comment: once you fix the logic error and are populating the List with the right values, you should go back to using Min

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're adding the current index(position) of entered number instead of the actual value. Change this:

```
arrayInt.Add(i);
```

To this:

```
arrayInt.Add(numbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `List.Add()` from 0 to 10. So you just got the result of minimum value 0. You may change it into `List.Add(number)` in your case.

Answer (score -1):

This hack should give you the min-value:

```
List<int> list = new List<int> { 5, 7, 3 };
list.Sort();
int minVal = list.First();
```

Result: minVal = 3

Comment: Time-complexity wise, this is slower than just traversing the list and keeping track of the min. O(nlogn) vs O(n). I doubt C# uses radix sort to sort ints so the sort will most likely take O(nlogn)

Comment: True - but it depends on how much data I have and if my application is time critical - in case of little data amounts it doesn't matter.